# While adding cucumber in eclipse I am getting an error

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber

Issue while adding cucumber in eclipse.
I tried with adding some jars , uninstall and install still facing issue. I have been facing this issue for last 2 months. And I am working on client network so I can't use some links like GitHub. I have to install cucumber from offline mode.

Cucumber editor jar file is present but in eclipse plugin it is not showing there. Please help me and give some solution on this persistent issue.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Cucumber Eclipse 1.0.0.201904151253(cucumber.eclipse.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201904151253)
Missing requirement: Cucumber Editor 1.0.0.201904151253 ( cucumber.eclipse.editor 1.0.0.201904151253) requires 'osgi.bundle;org.eclipse.pde.ui 3.5.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Cucumber Eclipse 1.0.0.201904151253(cucumber.eclipse.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201904151253)
To:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; cucumber.eclipse.editor[1.0.0.201904151253, 1.0.0.201904151253]

Comment: Install the Plug-in Development Environment from your Eclipse Project Updates update site first.

Comment: You need an Eclipse that includes Eclipse PDE (Plugin Dev. Env.) either by adding it to your existing Eclipse or downloading one of the packages that include it.